# Python authenticate as a Twitter application via python-twitter library

Tags: python, twitter

I implemented a Python app that is used python-twitter library.

Right now I am authenticated only as an user and get the responses successfully.
However, while reading a little bit the TwitterAPI I found that as a Twitter application I will be able to gather more information than a user.

Unfortunately, I did not understand how to do it with this library so I would glad for help.

I created a class named TwitterRequester:

```
class TwitterRequester:
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_twitter_api(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)

    def create_twitter_api(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret):
        self.api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=consumer_key,
                           consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
                           access_token_key=access_token_key,
                           access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

        logging.info("The twitter.Api object created")

    def get_friends(self):
        friends = self.api.GetFriends()
        return friends
```

In the run file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_requester = TwitterRequester()
    friends = twitter_requester.get_friends()
    print(friends)
```

I did not manage to understand how can I authenticate as an application with this particular library. Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The [pyhon-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) library does not support application authentication. You have to dig into the source code [here](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py#L227) to see this. Basically, for application authentication you would supply only the consumer key and the consumer secret (access token and access token secret are not required).

I suggest switching to another Python library that supports both user and application authentication, such as [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy]) or [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI).